# Generate Image and PDF with custom fonts using wkhtmltoimage and wkhtmltopdf (ALMA Linux , GODADDY VPS )

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

Basically I am trying to generate an image with html coded with inline csss blade template on laravel 9.One of my most important pririty was to use custom fonts on the template & generated image.I tried with every possible option I can get the fonts & font weight rendered on the image on my local server.But the font weight never works on the live vps server ..I had tried every possible solution for this but nothing seems to be working.I am adding the font on the template using base 64 method which is so far good but why the font weight never works on live vps server which I bought on godaddy.LIST OF THINGS I TRIED :

1.Uploading the fonts directly to my vps.

2.Base64 Font Encoding.

3.Using cloudinary for font loading.

4.Fontforge method.

5.Using Font Weight numeric & type version

THIS IS THE SAMPLE CODE OF MY BLADE FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>EAS NFT</title>
  </head>
<style>
  *{
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
  }
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'BourtonBase';
    src: url(@include('admin.nft.BourtonBase')) format('truetype');
}
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'BourtonBaseDrop';
    src: url(@include('admin.nft.BourtonBaseDrop')) format('truetype');
}
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'BourtonLineBold';
    src: url(@include('admin.nft.BourtonLineBold')) format('truetype');
    font-size: '10px';
    font-style: 'bold';
}
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'bourtonline';
    src: url(@include('admin.nft.bourtonline')) format('truetype');
    font-style: 'bold';
}
</style>
  <body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table
              border="0"
              bgcolor="#ffffff"
              cellpadding="0"
              cellspacing="'0"
              style="
                max-width: 512px;
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
                padding: 5px;
                background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/daxadnd2c/image/upload/v1697643021/ESA%20Nft/paper_nkwq3i.jpg');
                background-size: cover;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
              "
              align="center"
            >
              <tr style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
                <td style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
                  <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table
                            style="
                              background-color:{{ $nft->subcategory ? $nft->subcategory->bgColor : '#6c54ea' }} ;
                              color: #fff;
                              margin: 10px;
                              width: 96%;
                              border: 2px solid black;
                              padding: 18px 25px;
                            "
                          >
                            <tbody>
                              <td>
                                <h3
                                style="
                                    font-family: 'BourtonLineBold', sans-serif;
                                    font-size: 26px;
                                    margin: 0;
                                    padding-bottom: 15px;
                                    color: #fff;
                                    font-weight: 700;
                                    padding-bottom: 5px;
                                    letter-spacing:0.5px;
                                    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px
                                      rgba(34, 31, 31, 0.35);
                                  "
                              

BE NOTED I TRIED ALL THE POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS regarding this matter available on the google,stack overflow , github.

If any one can provide me any suggestions how can I fix the issue please ?
```